# Why can unsymmetrical tert-butyl ethers be prepared by dehydration of the constituent alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

[image]

Practice problem 11.11 what stops R-O-R from forming at the same rate as the desired product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to understand why this is OK, you have to understand the mechanism by which this occurs. It is essentially an $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction that is most favoured by the conditions (acidic + polar protic solvent).

So, for the formation of an ether $\ce{^tBu-O-R}$ where $\ce{R}$ is a primary alkyl group:

- competing formation of $\ce{R-O-R}$ is slow because primary carbocations are very unstable, and
- competing formation of $\ce{^tBu-O-^tBu}$ is slow because $\ce{^tBuOH}$ is a poor nucleophile (tertiary alcohols are very bulky).

Comment: What stops an SN2 mechanism from operating to form  ROR?

Comment: @xasthor Water is a bad leaving group for an SN2 reaction – the *tert*-butyl cation is stable enough to promote loss of water (in an SN1 sense), then ROH can attack (tBuOH is a terrible nucleophile).. there really is only 1 favoured outcome in this reaction..

Comment: @NotEvans, H2O+ is not a bad leaving group. Besides, if it was a bad leaving group, it would not only affect the SN2 rate but also affect the SN1 rate

Comment: SN2 displacement of a primary alcohol (as in an SN2) without prior activation is not a favourable/well known reaction.  Look in any organic chemistry textbook (I suggest Clayden...)- it's well explained and it may help to clarify the basics for you :)

Comment: @xasthor I think what you are saying is that *after protonation*, it is possible for $\ce{ROH2+}$ to react in an SN2. Yes, it is possible - but then there is no good nucleophile (alcohols are really quite poor). Compared to the SN1 reaction which has everything going for it (very polar solvent + tertiary cation), I don't think it's likely that this SN2 can be competitive in terms of rate. Maybe, at most, you get some side product. If you compare to generic ROH + R'OH, which simply produces a hopeless mixture... this is much better.

Comment: A key info here is the room T vs the 100+Celsius to form primary ethers. Ether formation is probably an SN2 reaction on a protonated alcohol. Slow addition of t-butyl alcohol to an acidified primary alcohol should give good yields and minimize side reactions. The t-butyl cation should be immediately attacked by the alcohol molecules solvating the protonated alcohol. It would be interesting to react optically active 3-methyl hexan-3-ol and compare to a Williamson synthesis.